# Create 1000 turtles near each others

Tags: netlogo

I have to create a lot of turtles forming a compact group of any shape, a simple 10x100 rectangle is enough. The important thing is that they must be near each others.
In c i would do something like this:

```
for(x = 1; x <= rows; x++)
{
    for(y = 1; y <= columns; y++)
    {
        create_turtle(x,y);
    }
}
```

And the equivalent in netlogo would be:

```
crt 1000
let n 0
let x 1
let y 1
while[y <= 10]
[
  set x 1
  while[x <= 100]
  [
    ask turtle n
    [move-to patch x y]  
    set x x + 1
    set n n + 1      
  ]
  set y y + 1    
]
```

But it's not an elegant solution. Any suggestion?

Edit: More precisely I have to reproduce what has been done in this article: http://science.sciencemag.org/content/345/6198/795.full 
Every turtle is a little robot. 
And here you can see one way turtles could be positioned [turtles schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W23HH.jpg) 
I'm using circle turtles like the robots of the article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the trickiest things for programmers from other languages to do when learning NetLogo is getting rid of all the loops. Iterating through the agents or patches is embedded in the `ask` primitive, you don't need to code the iteration. `ask` also iterates in a random order so that repeated processes don't lead to any advantage to whichever agent happens to be first in the loop.

Also, when you create turtles, you can immediately give them instructions. You can also place them initially in an arbitrary position rather than move them there. Here is one solution that places them all in a rectangle that is 5 patches to the left/right of centre (0,0) and occupies half the height of the world.

```
create-turtles 1000 [ setxy random-float 10 - 5 random-ycor * 0.5 ]
```

From the edit, I think you are wanting them to be created at gridpoints rather than randomly within the space. If that is true, then select the `patches` you want and ask them to `sprout` a turtle.

```
let in-shape patches with [ pxcor >= -10 and pxcor <= 10 and pycor >= -10 and pycor <= 10 ]
ask in-shape [ sprout 1 ]
```

You will need to work out your own values and make sure they are within the world dimension.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but my problem is a little different. I tried to explain it better editing my initial question.

Comment: try this. If it's still not what you want, please describe what is wrong with it.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what i need.

Comment: "getting rid of all the loops" is wise advice. The zen of NetLogo embraces looplessness.

Comment: Yes, i'm starting to understand that.